# Batch file to create a folder in every removable device

Tags: windows, batch-file, removable-media

i Need a batch file to create a folder "test" in every removable device than i plug in my computer (pendrives and etc) 
i am trying something like this

```
set "extDrive="
for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get driveLetter^ where drivertype=2 ) do set extDrive=%%D
mkdir "%extDrive%\test"
```

Someone can tell me why this is not working ??

Answer (score 1):

#### Why is this not working?

> 'wmic volume get driveLetter^ where drivertype=2

You have several errors in the above `wmic` command:

- `drivertype` should be `drivetype`.
- There is a missing trailing `'`.
- The `^ is not needed.
- The `where` should come before the `get`.
- Not all disk volumes have drive letters (but logical disks do).

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (
  if [%%e]==[2] echo mkdir %%d\test
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Remove the `echo` before `mkdir` when you have tested the batch file.
- You may need to do something with drive type 3 as well.
- I have a removable drive of type 3. In the below output C: is a fixed hard disk, D: is my CD ROM drive, E: is a removable USB stick and F: is a removable external USB drive.

  ```
  F:\test>wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, drivetype
  DeviceID  DriveType
  C:        3
  D:        5
  E:        2
  F:        3
  ```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Answer (score 0):

to get the drive letter of a removable drive use:
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid

in my case this returns: 
C:\Windows\system32>wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid
DeviceID
E:

i would put this to a txt file, and then loop through that text file...
Im not a big batch programmer, this way is easier to debug for me. :)